# How to Select all buttons and alert their respective name when CLICKED in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  var buttonClicked = $("button").attr("name");
  alert("Button CLicked: " + buttonClicked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="titleClass">jQuery</h1>
<div class="buttonClass">
    <button name="up_button" id="upB" class="upDown"></button>
    <button name="left_button" id="leftB" class="leftRight"></button>
    <button name="right_button" id="rightB" class="leftRight"></button>
    <button name="down_button" id="downB" class="upDown"></button>
</div>
```

I want to display the name (as alert or console.log) when a button is clicked from the above list

```
 $("button").on("click", function(){
   var buttonClicked = $("button").attr("name");
   alert("Button CLicked: " + buttonClicked);
 })
```

Answer (score 1):

you are already calling the `$("button")` as `eventlistener`. Instead of calling another `$("button")` in variable initialization, use `$(this)`

```
 var buttonClicked = $(this).attr("name");
```

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  var buttonClicked = $(this).attr("name");
  alert("Button CLicked: " + buttonClicked);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="titleClass">jQuery</h1>
<div class="buttonClass">
    <button name="up_button" id="upB" class="upDown"></button>
    <button name="left_button" id="leftB" class="leftRight"></button>
    <button name="right_button" id="rightB" class="leftRight"></button>
    <button name="down_button" id="downB" class="upDown"></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    
    <h1 class="titleClass">jQuery</h1>
    <div class="buttonClass">
        <button name="up_button" id="upB" class="upDown">A</button>
        <button name="left_button" id="leftB" class="leftRight">B</button>
        <button name="right_button" id="rightB" class="leftRight">C</button>
        <button name="down_button" id="downB" class="upDown">D</button>
    </div>
    

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
        $("button").on("click", function(e){
        var buttonClicked = $("button").attr("name");
                console.log(e.target.name)
        }) 
    </script>
</body>
```

Just need to have the event handler with event argument, and use `event.target.value`to get the value of button that is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".buttonClass").on("click", function (event) {
    var buttonClicked = event.target.name;
    alert("Button CLicked: " + buttonClicked);
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
     var buttonClicked = $(this).attr("name");
     alert("Button CLicked: " + buttonClicked);
})
```

$(this) will select the object of clicked button